# Get unique fields in elasticsearch database using python

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm accessing an elasticsearch database. I'm not looking for a way to get a list of unique ids, without actually getting data. My data (one entry as example) is formatted like this:

```
res['hits']['hits'] = 
    {'_index': 'md',
     '_type': 'appevents',
     '_id': 'XXXXXX',
     '_score': 1.0,
     '_source': {
         'endTimeMillis': 1519143592708,
         'id': 'fc4507cc-a819-4acc-a8af-768923fb4dec',
         ... # A whole bunch of vars that are not relevant here
                }
    }
```

I tried using aggs:

```
body = {

    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_ids": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "id"
            }
        }
    }

}

res = es.search(index="md",
                body=body,
                request_timeout=60,
                doc_type='appevents')
```

... but I get a 400 (request does not support size). I tried several things, but I can't get the format of the request right. Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: It looks like `es.search()` receives a size argument, have you tried to set that to "0" (and remove the size indication from your body json)

Comment: Just did, and the size error is gone. It now gives my a different error though: TransportError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'request does not support [aggs]'